# Many-to-Many relationship in Access from a single table

Tags: ms-access, many-to-many, relationships, database-normalization, junction-table

I browsed the web but couldn't seem to find an answer to my question.

I know it is possible to create a Junction table between two tables in order to create a many-to-many relationship between them, but is it also possible to create a many-to-many relationship from a single table ?

I have a table `Books`, with `IDs`, `Titles` etc. I need to record in another table (the Junction table of my many-to many relationship) *which books are mentioned in a specific book*. It means I will have multiple records linked to a single book in that table.

It seems to me like a many-to-many relationship since one book can mention multiple other books, and many books can speak about a single book.

To refine my question : is there a way to create a two-way relationship between my `Books` table and a `Junction` table in Access? I tried to do so but Access seems to create a duplicate of my Books table (called Book1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct. The seemingly duplicate table `Book1` is only shown to visualize the additional relationship from the Junction table to `Book`. It is not actually duplicated.

So your relationships are probably already right. If you add a link to a screenshot of your relationship window, we can confirm that.

Comment: Oh indeed, the table is not duplicated like I thought. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

You should have the main table tblBook. 
Then a second table for your many to many relationships. This will include the parentBookID and the childBookID. When querying you simple use tblBook twice (giving it a different name in the query the second time) with the relationship table between them. 
Select * 
from tblBook left join relRefrences on tblBook.Id = relRefrences.ParentBookID 
        left join tblBook as refBooks on relRefrences.childBookID = refbooks.Id

Doing it on my phone so excuse formatting.